uuid, I am getting in logs but not for each thread. only getting in main thread. Have to add in splunk logs
So, first time I have worked on splunk part where I have integrated myspringboot application with splunk.
To uniquely identify my logs for application execution, I tried to add one uuid, for that, I modified log4j2.xml.
file path:- src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logging.file.name">info-log</Property>
        <Property name="logging.file.path">./</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [thread - %thread] [%-5level] | uuid='%X{uuid}' | [Method Name - %M] -- %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <!-- File Appender to read from info-log file -->
        <File name="INFO_FILE" fileName="${logging.file.path}/${logging.file.name}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [thread - %thread] [%-5level] | uuid='%X{uuid}' | [Method Name - %M] -- %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
        <!-- SplunkHttp Appender to send logs to Splunk -->
        <SplunkHttp
                name="splunkhttp"
                url="http://localhost:8088"
                token="f873377f-b48b-4022-88c9-922564ae9854"
                host="localhost"
                index="order_api_dev"
                type="raw"
                source="http-event-logs"
                sourcetype="log4j"
                messageFormat="text"
                disableCertificateValidation="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m" />
        </SplunkHttp>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="INFO_FILE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="splunkhttp"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.example" level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="splunkhttp"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

After that I was able to generate uuid in console but the moment my method executed which I have written in controller or service class, for that uuid we are getting empty.
2024-09-23 11:55:57.631 [thread - main] [WARN ] | uuid='5ed72e5b-c6b4-44c1-b9ce-dbd59bc6bd09' | [Method Name - openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor] -- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-09-23 11:55:58.599 [thread - main] [INFO ] | uuid='5ed72e5b-c6b4-44c1-b9ce-dbd59bc6bd09' | [Method Name - log] -- org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2024-09-23 11:55:58.674 [thread - main] [INFO ] | uuid='5ed72e5b-c6b4-44c1-b9ce-dbd59bc6bd09' | [Method Name - start] -- org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-09-23 11:55:58.687 [thread - main] [INFO ] | **uuid='5ed72e5b-c6b4-44c1-b9ce-dbd59bc6bd09'** | [Method Name - logStarted] -- com.example.DemoApplication - Started DemoApplication in 10.893 seconds (JVM running for 13.985)
2024-09-23 11:56:29.092 [thread - http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] | **uuid=''** | [Method Name - log] -- org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-23 11:56:29.092 [thread - http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] | uuid='' | [Method Name - initServletBean] -- org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-23 11:56:29.100 [thread - http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] | uuid='' | [Method Name - initServletBean] -- org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 8 ms
2024-09-23 11:56:29.341 [thread - http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] | uuid='' | [Method Name - createDepartment] -- com.example.controller.DepartmentController - Entering createDepartment method with request: /departments
2024-09-23 11:56:29.342 [thread - http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] | uuid='' | [Method Name - createDepartment] -- com.example.controller.DepartmentController - Request Parameter: Computer
2024-09-23 11:56:29.521 [thread - http-nio-8080-exec-2] [INFO ] | uuid='' | [Method Name - writeLog] -- net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.logging.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:Proxy DataSource, Connection:4, Time:8, Success:True, Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0, Query:["insert into department (id, name) values (default, ?)"], Params:[(Computer)]

Well, I have modified the main file to generate UUID
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // Put the UUID value into the ThreadContext map
        ThreadContext.put("uuid", uuid);
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

What could be the issue?

You only place it in the main thread, why should that leak to other threads? You need a filter to do something like this, or even better ditch your own attempts and use the build in tracing abilities from Micrometer integrated into Spring / Spring Boot and various other projects.

Quick Guide to Micrometer at baeldung.com.
